# How can I convert several .ai files to various sized .png files automatically?

Tags: graphics, automation, png, vector-graphics

I am making a deck of cards in Adobe Illustrator.  Each card is saved as it's own .ai file so I can change it later if I want to.  When using these images in an iOS app, I must convert everything to .png files.  Then I must re-size those .png files to have retina and non retina versions.  I'm hoping there is a way that will allow me to automatically take a folder of all my .ai files and give .pngs of 200px x 400px and 100 x 200px.  Also I'd like the larger ones to automatically be named @2xNameOfOrginalFile.png and the others to be named nameOfOrginalFile.png.  I see stuff about batch automated scripting that does stuff like that.  I'm curious how simple that is to implement.  Is what I'm suggesting possible?  Is this an easy process?

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty easy to do. Someone has posted a script that will do what you want: http://forums.adobe.com/message/4915819

You'll have to change these lines,

```
pngExportOpts.horizontalScale = 250.0;
pngExportOpts.verticalScale = 250.0;
```

to calculated values. The scale is a percentage (see: [the docs](http://cssdk.host.adobe.com/sdk/1.0/docs/WebHelp/references/csawlib/com/adobe/illustrator/ExportOptionsPNG24.html)). You can use sourceDoc.width and sourceDoc.height to get the width and height of the original .ai file (in pixels? docs don't say).

You'll also want to modify the getNewName function.

Comment: I was thinking this was something I'd do inside of Illustrator.  Where exactly am I writing this code?

Comment: See page 10 of the Illustrator Scripting Guide: http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/illustrator/scripting/cs6/Illustrator-Scripting-Guide.pdf